# Установка прокси про помощи os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']

Tags: python, proxy, ос

Как я понимаю **os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY']** устанавливает прокси на всю систему.
Как мне проверить работают ли прокси? Вот код:

```
import os    
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'https://5.61.58.211:4408'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://5.61.58.211:4408'
```

Comment: Оно только прописывает строку в переменную окружения и больше ничего. Будет ли эта строка восприниматься как прокси — зависит от поведения конкретного приложения

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib, requests
print(requests.get("https://api.ipify.org").text)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]